# Output Impedance of BJT/Mosfet amplifiers

Tags: mosfet, bjt, impedance

I have heard in lectures that the desired output impedance for the BJT/Mosfet Amplifiers is LOW. But these transistors are Transconductance amplifiers 'by birth'. I mean they give output current proportional to the input voltage. So WHY should there be low impedance. I think we need HIGH output impedance. Really confused.
Thanks
Salil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But these transistors are Transconductance amplifiers 'by birth'. I
>   mean they give output current proportional to the input voltage.

When operated as a common source/emitter amplifier your point is true. When operated as common drain/collector, the output impedance is low. Typically, for a BJT using the emitter as an output (virtually unity gain), the transistor can feed a wide range of loads without much change in the output voltage.

The desired output is usually low impedance for such things as audio power amplifiers (push-pull common collector/drain) because they need to drive low impedances such as 8 ohm speakers.

Comment: Thanks Andy. But does that mean that every amplifier design has to have a common collector/drain as the output stage.

Comment: No it doesn't - the collector/drain resistor defines the output impedance and if you require an output impedance of (say) 600 ohms then a 600 ohm resistor will do the job. Power amps (audio to RF) require low output impedance and this is most effectively served by an emitter/source output amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, we do not "NEED HIGH" output impedances (with some exceptions like OTA`s, for example). However, not all of our wishes come true. Hence, it is true what you have learned: That the **desired** output impedance for the BJT/Mosfet Amplifiers is LOW. However, as you correctly have stated, BJT and FET are transconductance devices with a relatively large output resistance. Therefore, in order to become independent on the load conditions, in many cases a separate output stage is needed that provides no additional gain but (only) a low output impedance.